# DLHR differential pressure sensor library for SAMD boards

Tags: arduino

I am trying to find a library for the DLHR E1BD differential pressure sensor (made by AllSensors) for a SAMD board or ESP32.

The existing library does not compile for the SAMD boards. i.e. when I select any of the SAMD boards (Nano33IoT, MKR NB 1500, etc) the simpl example sketch does not compile.

This is the compiling error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\misha\Dropbox\My Own\9. ArduinoLibraries\libraries\arduino_923018\src\AllSensors_DLHR.cpp:16:10: fatal error: util/delay.h: No such file or directory

 #include <util/delay.h>
```

There is a library but it is for the old AVR boards, but does anyone know of a library for the SAMD boards?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A quick look at the data sheet says it supports I2C and SPI. I'd expect that the part specific libraries call the base communication libraries, so should be the same for all Arduino variants - have you tried them and what issue did you find?

Comment: Hi Pete. Thank you for your reply. Apologies, I should have included that in the original question. Please see question for update.

Comment: if the library uses the Wire library or the SPI library, then it should work on all 'architectures'

Comment: Please see above to the compiling error using a MKR NB 1500 board

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is from two missing include files:

```
 #include <math.h>
 #include <util/delay.h>
```

which are at least for Arduino standard libs of the core

```
#include <math.h>
```

can be ditched if you include Arduino.h in your *.ino as first lib

```
#include <util/delay.h>
```

should be added by the compiler anyway so rem them out in AllSensors_DLHR.cpp

For SAM boards I did not find them in the installed core (1.6.12) so just try a compile for SAM with those libs remed

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I did as you suggested. I also had to change another line "_delay_us(100);". I replaced that with "delayMicroseconds(100);". The library now compiled fine. But once the upload was done the MKR 1500 stopped being visible on any port. Had to reset by double clicking reset button to reestablish connection.

Comment: Now your program would help to identify the cause of this.I dont know the SAMD but my ESP32have to be resettedtowork after flashing.